# How to connect remote mongo db in django

Tags: django, mongodb

I am trying to connect with remote mongoDB in with the help of Django in my local system it is not happening

I am Using atom IDE i configured and installed djongo for mongoDB

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'Test_Jango',
   }
}
```

I am expecting to connect remote MongoDb with Django.

Comment: What errors are you facing?

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi it is throwing an error i.e  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your password.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'Test_Jango',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_password',
   }
}
```

The `settings.py` supports the following options:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': True
            'NAME': 'your-db-name',
            'HOST': 'host-name or ip address',
            'PORT': port_number,
            'USER': 'db-username',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'AUTH_SOURCE': 'db-name',
            'AUTH_MECHANISM': 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
            'REPLICASET': 'replicaset',
            'SSL': 'ssl',
            'SSL_CERTFILE': 'ssl_certfile',
            'SSL_CA_CERTS': 'ssl_ca_certs',
            'READ_PREFERENCE': 'read_preference'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also you may need to set the `HOST` and `PORT`

Comment: @Manzurul Hoque Rumi I am able connect now thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: Has anyone tried to pass multiple hosts for the replicaset connection?

Answer (score 2):

For the current version of djongo (1.3.4), many of the settings have been moved into a `CLIENT` section.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "djongo",
        "NAME": "your-db-name",
        "CLIENT": {
            "host": "db1.mongo.example.com",
            "port": 27017,
            "username": "...",
            "password": "...",
            "authSource": "admin",
        },
    },
```

See the [Database Configuration](https://www.djongomapper.com/get-started/#database-configuration) section on the [Get Started](https://www.djongomapper.com/get-started/) page of the official documentation for more details.

It's unclear at exactly which version this changed but the code change is from [this commit](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/commit/16bc5b40dd8ae98e8e1770a8b9e6f41902850050#diff-c47a88aec477f8b75330aa16dc6352e8285f0634b29239d8f7d205d7fd6e1fae) on Feb 8, 2020, so around version 1.3.1 according to the package's [release history timeline](https://pypi.org/project/djongo/#history).